# Can you set the default ID strategy for Doctrine ODM?

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine, odm

When setting up annotations with Doctrine ODM for the id field of a document you can specify a different key generation strategy that the default MongoId method like so:

```
/** @ODM\Document(collection="documents") */
class Document
{
    /**
    * @ODM\Id(strategy="UUID")
    */
    protected $id;
}
```

This requires you to specify this strategy for every new document mapping you set up.  Is it possible to change the default strategy for your entire application?  Maybe via a configuration option at the connection level?

Comment: did you find any answer for your question ??

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the inheritance enough?

```
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as ODM;

/** @ODM\Document */
abstract class AbstractDocument
{
   /**
   * @ODM\Id(strategy="UUID")
   */
   protected $id;

   public function getId()
   {
      return $this->id;
   }
}

/** @ODM\Document(collection="MyDocument") */
class MyDocument extends AbstractDocument {}

/** @ODM\Document(collection="AnotherDocument") */
class AnotherDocument extends AbstractDocument {}
```

then you can:

```
$myDocument = new MyDocument();
$odm->persist($myDocument);
$odm>flush();
$myDocument->getId();
```